# "Опубликовано" или "опубликованы"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: *На данный момент в журнале X опубликовано 5 моих статей* или *На данный момент в журнале X опубликованы 5 моих статей*?

Answer (score 3):

Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совокупность предметов, форма множественного числа – на отдельные предметы. Ср.: В городе строится пять объектов соцкультбыта (единое нерасчлененное представление о действии). – В крупнейших городах страны строятся еще пять объектов соцкультбыта (расчлененное представление о действии). Ср. также: В крендельной работало двадцать шесть человек... (Горький). – Восемь самолетов полка взлетали попарно, соблюдая очередь (Н. Чуковский). 
   Поэтому при подлежащем, обозначающем большое число предметов и воспринимаемом как одно целое, сказуемое обычно ставится в единственном числе, например: В столовой в одну смену сидело сто человек (Макаренко); Прибыло шестьсот студентов-путейцев (Н. Островский).

Я бы написал "опубликовано".

Comment: А если статей не пять а две? Корректно ли предложение "я опубликовал две статьи"? ( статьи в именительном падеже, а не в родительном как в примерах). Ведь как говорит Аллазар  опубликовано статьи уже не корректно

Comment: @user190920 Это винительный падеж: опубликовал кого/что.

Comment: хмм... наверное. Я просто по другому это представлял. опубликовал кого/что ? две, две чего? статьи. Шутка)

Answer (score 3):

Упоминание в предложении о "*данном моменте*" делает более вероятным *количественную* значимость сообщения. Поэтому предпочтителен вариант: *"(на данный момент) опубликован**о** [**сколько уже**] пять моих статей"* (напр. этого хватит для списка публикаций по теме диссертации).

При отсутствии такого упоминания был бы возможен дополнительный контекст, акцентирующий не *количество*, а индивидуальные (добавленный перечень названий) или групповые (что их объединяет - общая тема, время или место написания) *особенности* этих статей, например:

> В журнале опубликован**ы** пять моих статей [**какие именно пять**] - те,
>   что я написал в Болдине(-о).

Answer (score 0):

Немаловажную роль здесь играет числительное. Попробуйте его убрать: "опубликовано статьи" - не корректно, "опубликовано 5 статей" - приемлемо вполне. В данном предложении целое числительное "пять" является частью подлежащего и именно оно определяет единственное число сказуемого "опубликовано". Без него число определяло бы существительное" статьи" :"в журнале х были опубликованы мои статьи".